# Mi sesion de login se cierra cuando mi pasarela de pagos me regresa la informacion en una variable POST estoy usando LARAVEL 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Que tal estoy construyendo una aplicacion web que se conecta con una pasarela de pagos llamada PROSA aqui en Mexico. Mi sistema tiene autenticacion de usuarios para todas las rutas. Para poder procesar los pagos hago que mi sistema redireccione a la url de la pasarela de pagos para que el usuario ponga los datos de su tarjeta, hasta todo bien. El problema viene cuando el usuario realiza el pago y PROSA me regresa la peticion POST de ese pago a mi url, cuando sucede esto puedo ver la informacion de la variable pero mi sesion de usuario desaparece, necesito volver a realizar el login a mi aplicacion.

Quite la proteccion en el middleware CSRF de mi url ligada al controlador donde recibo el $request de PROSA, pero no entiendo porque al momento de pasar por esa ruta en mi sistema, pierdo mi sesion de usuario.

Estoy utilizando Laravel 7

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'https://portal.inscripciones.giganube.com.mx/prosa',
        'https://www.procom.prosa.com.mx/*'
    ];
}
```

Aqui recibo la informacion de prosa por medio de POST, ellos me regresan un objeto JSON:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo evitar que se cierre mi sesion para poder mostrarle al usuario la informacion de validacion de pago que me regresa PROSA?

Comment: Si a lo que te refieres es que el POST que te manda PROSA no se procesa porque el route está protegido por autenticacion de usuarios, el problema seguramente no venga de que tu sesión se pierda, sino que el que está haciendo POST es prosa ( quien realmente no tiene sesión iniciada como usuario ) y no tu.

Comment: El problema es que al momento de que PROSA me responde redireccionadomen a mi dominio con  POST desde su aplicacion el navegador pierde la sesion que tengo en laravel. Tuve que realizar login de nuevo en mi controlador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion que encontre fue, como prosa genera un POST desde su aplicacion a la mia, por seguridad el navegador pierde la sesion de mi aplicacion. Por lo cual al momento de que prosa me manda  su POST con informacion vuelvo a generar login desde el controlador con la instruccion:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($prosa['user_id']);
```

Yo le paso a PROSA el id de mi user autenticado, y de regreso vuelvo a acceder a ese mismo usuario. Algo arcaico pero esta pasarela de pago deja mucho que desear.